# Examining the Behaviour of Hyperledger Fabric when one of the stateDB is Tampered

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger

https://kctheservant.medium.com/exploring-the-behaviour-of-hyperledger-fabric-when-world-state-is-tampered-764676fe90f2

I am trying a similar approach as in this link but with some changes. I want to examine the same scenario with only one organisation and two peers.

I looked it up and people had suggested to make both the peers and endorsing peers or either just create one more organisation. Couldn't find anything helpful in the hyperledger docs as well. Can someone please help me with this. Also, I am fairly new to all of this.

Using hyperledger-fabric version 2.3.0

Comment: Might you please [edit] your question so that it is self-contained and can be understood without reference to an external article?  As explained in [Should posts be self-contained?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18669), it's important for readers to be able to understand your question even if the linked content is deleted.  And after scanning that article, it's still not clear what your question is or how it might be answered.  What have you tried, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Take a look at [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/.  Might you please [edit] your question along the lines suggested?  This is a programming Q&A site so you're most likely to get help if you can show the code you have so far (a [mcve]) and clearly state what you need to do nex.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have the AND endorsement policy in the chaincode and then invoke the transaction.
The possible solutions to your problem are

1. Make both the peers as endorsing peers or
2. Add a new organization to your network

You need to have the AND endorsement policies to mimic this scenario. Whenever we invoke the chaincode we need to pass the endorsing peers using the `--peerAddresses` and their TLS certificates using `--tlsRootCertFiles` flags

```
peer chaincode invoke -n basic -C mychannel -o localhost:7050 --ordererTLSHostnameOverride orderer.example.com  --tls --cafile "$ORDERER_CA" --peerAddresses localhost:7051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org1.example.com/peers/peer0.org1.example.com/tls/ca.crt --peerAddresses localhost:9051 --tlsRootCertFiles ${PWD}/organizations/peerOrganizations/org2.example.com/peers/peer0.org2.example.com/tls/ca.crt  -c '{"Args":["CreateAsset", "1001","red", "20","aditya","100"]}'
```